# OpenCV arithmetic operations on matrices

Tags: opencv, matrix

Can someone explain the following, totally unintuitive, results:

```
Mat_<Vec3f> mat(Size(3,3),0);
Mat_<Vec3f> mat_add = (mat + 9);
Mat_<Vec3f> mat_add_div = (mat + 9) / 3;
```

magically, I don't have any other explanation for it:

```
mat_add =     [9,0,0,9,0,0,9,0,0];
mat_add_div = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3];
```

**EDIT**:

My take: this is a legacy bug that can't be fixed anymore because it is retroactive and will impact lot of projects. Also it would be pretty nasty to debug (except project has already pretty thorough unit testing)

Answer (score 2):

```
Mat_<Vec3f> mat_add = (mat + 9);
```

is equivalent to

```
Mat_<Vec3f> temp(Size(3,3),Vec3f(9,0,0));
Mat_<Vec3f> mat_add = mat+temp;
```

So, you will get

```
mat_add =
        [9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0;
          9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0;
          9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0]
```

---

However, I have no clue for why you will get values like that for `mat_add_div`. In fact, if you replace it by:

```
Mat_<Vec3f> mat_add_div = mat_add / 3;
```

You will end up with

```
mat_add_div =
        [3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0;
          3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0;
          3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]
```

This result is however reasonable based on the same theory as said in above.

Comment: mat_add_div =[3,0,0...] would be indeed reasonable, even though counter-intuitive (I guess there many more cases where you want to add a scalar to the whole matrix instead of the R channel only).

Comment: @memecs Then, you'd better to use `Vec3f(9,9,9)` instead of `9` for safe and for better readability.

Comment: Well yes, if I knew the type of my matrix. How would you handle the case (without and if/else) in which mat is either Vec3f or float?

Comment: ... and by the way I found of (mat + a) /b looking at tonemapping.hpp in the new photo/hdr submodule.